# Does the Saint Epic Destiny and Mark of Healing stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, cleric

The Saint epic destiny has a feature that indicates

> When you enable a creature adjacent to you to spend a healing surge, the recipient can also make a saving throw. When you grant a saving throw to a creature adjacent to you, that creature can also spend a healing surge.

Mark of Healing

> Whenever you use a healing power on an ally or use Heal to allow an ally to spend his or her second wind, that ally can also make a saving throw.

If a cleric with both uses healing word on an adjacent ally, does the target get two healing surges and two saving throws?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

Under the condition you stated, when you use [Healing Word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1455) on an ally, you also grant him a saving throw (per [Mark of Healing](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1390)).
Having provided him a healing surge expenditure, you also provide him a saving throw (per [Sanctified Touch](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=449) feature).
Having provided him a saving throw via [Mark of Healing](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1390) you also grant him another expenditure of a healing throw (via [Sanctified Touch](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/epicdestiny.aspx?id=449) feature).

So the net gain is of 2 healing surge expenditures and 2 saving throws with a single application of [Healing Word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1455).

You can't use two [Healing Word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1455) applications in the same round (unless some other feat or features that I missed). Also, at epic levels you have three application of [Healing Word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1455) per encounter (not 2).

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing there to prevent the recipient from receiving both saving throws.

However, it should be noted that because the ED feature there does not have the heal keyword (and isn't a power), you cannot get into an infinite save heal loop.